# Android: How to get the value of a TAG: with XmlPullParser

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, parsing, xmlpullparser

as the title states, with XmlPullParser, it is possibile to get the Tags of an XML document, with a function that looks as the following:

```
  public static void parseXML(Context context) {
        XmlPullParserFactory parserFactory;
        try {
            parserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser parser = parserFactory.newPullParser();
            InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("example.xml");
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(is, null);

            processParsing(parser);

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
}

public static void processParsing(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException{
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String eltName = null;

            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    eltName = parser.getName();

                    System.out.println(eltName); //Delievers the TAG-Name
                    System.out.println(parser.getText()); // Should deliever the TAG-Value - delievers 'null'
                    System.out.println(parser.nextText()); // Also doesn't give out any value.

                    break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
    }
```

XML: `example.xml`

```
<players>
    <player>
        <name>Lebron James</name>
        <age>32</age>
        <position>SF/PF</position>
    </player>
    <player>
        <name>Kevin Durant</name>
        <age>29</age>
        <position>SF/PF</position>
    </player>
    <player>
        <name>Stephen Curry</name>
        <age>29</age>
        <position>PG</position>
    </player>
</players>
```

**Issue:** `System.out.println(parser.getText());` // Should deliever the TAG-Value - delievers 'null'
`System.out.println(parser.nextText());` // Also doesn't give out any value.

**Question:** How to get the value of the Tags in the given XML-Document?

How to get the Value

Answer (score 0):

For fetching the text, you need to have another case here:

> case XmlPullParser.TEXT:

And then inside that block, you can get the text.

> parser.getText()